# Nodejs + Redis performance on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, redis

We have an nodejs application sat on Azure using Redis to cache data from various external endpoints so we don't exhaust API limits unnecessarily and to keep page render times fast despite some extremely slow endpoints.

As the application has scaled we've started to get some issues with Redis performance. I put some logging around `get` `setex` calls to track response times and in some cases they can be over 500ms per call. However according to the Azure dashboard redis server load is fine.
[image]

As a bit of background the application is hosted in 3 regions with an app service and redis cache in each. There can be up to 20 app service hosts per region. There is no cross communication between the redis caches as there is no requirement for the data to be in sync across regions, and to allow for an entire region to fall with no loss in service. We create a single redis client per running process and that is shared.

We're running nodejs 14 and using ioredis 4.27.6 and our config is

```js
const client = new Redis({
  port,
  host: server,
  password: auth,
  maxRetriesPerRequest: 2,
  tls: {},
  enableAutoPipelining: true,
  enableOfflineQueue: true,
  connectTimeout: 30000,
});
```

An some example of the slow logging

```
2021-10-10T09:10:53.369997968Z warn: redis slow redis {
2021-10-10T09:10:53.370045469Z   "command": "setex",
2021-10-10T09:10:53.370053669Z   "diffMs": 611,
2021-10-10T09:10:53.370065369Z   "key": "getRolloutValue(product_over)"
2021-10-10T09:10:53.370070169Z }
2021-10-10T09:10:53.376250740Z warn: redis slow redis {
2021-10-10T09:10:53.376285841Z   "command": "get",
2021-10-10T09:10:53.376293841Z   "diffMs": 487,
2021-10-10T09:10:53.376303141Z   "key": "getDataForProduct(enus, XXXX)",
2021-10-10T09:10:53.376328241Z   "sizeStr": "8.93 KB"
2021-10-10T09:10:53.376332641Z }
2021-10-10T09:10:53.377994061Z warn: redis slow redis {
2021-10-10T09:10:53.378021261Z   "command": "get",
2021-10-10T09:10:53.378028661Z   "diffMs": 488,
2021-10-10T09:10:53.378037261Z   "key": "getDataForProduct(enus, XXXX)",
2021-10-10T09:10:53.378045661Z   "sizeStr": "5.45 KB"
2021-10-10T09:10:53.378049961Z }
```

Has anyone experienced this or have any advice regarding configuration on how we can improve performance?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the slow reason is not redis self, but from Operating System Context Switching, the cpu was occupied by other processes. You can try run redis in a  isolated environment, without any other applications.

Comment: Redis thinks its own cache latency is low based on the provided metrics which leads me to believe the issue is somewhere from the network connection to the redis box to the node.js process.

Comment: check https://redis.io/commands/slowlog. The Redis Slow Log is a system to log queries that exceeded a specified execution time. The execution time does not include I/O operations like talking with the client, sending the reply and so forth, but just the time needed to actually execute the command (this is the only stage of command execution where the thread is blocked and can not serve other requests in the meantime).

Comment: your `get` command cost much, means the cpu occupied.